# Setting radio buttons with setField in datalink (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a need to set radio buttons using the setField() method from datalink (the jQuery plugin).

I have read the issues around this on gitHub and seen a fork to address it (https://github.com/jamiemthomas/jquery-datalink), but this is for older versions of jQuery.

What would be an easy way to update radio buttons using the datalink plugin's setField method, perhaps with a slight modification? Maybe there are other alternatives / plugins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to a comment from an issue logged on this (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-datalink/issues/14#issuecomment-531732), I have adapted the hack found there. By changing the setField method as follows, it works:

(EDIT - added code for setting checkbox as well).

Before:

```
    if ( target.nodeType ) {
        var setter = fnSetters[ field ] || "attr";
        $(target)[setter](value);
```

After:

```
    if ( target.nodeType ) {
        var setter = fnSetters[ field ] || "attr";
        /* Hack to set radio buttons */
        if ($(target).is(':radio')) {
            $(target).parent().children(":radio[value='" + value + "']").attr('checked', true);
        } else if ($(target).is(':checkbox')) {
            if (target.value == value) $(target).attr('checked', true);
        } else {
            $(target)[setter](value);
        }
```

EDIT - I have also forked the original datalink project on GitHub and added these changes: https://github.com/mydoghasworms/jquery-datalink/

Comment: Do you have any demoes that show this functionality working? I'm trying it myself and not having any luck. I've added debugger lines to the setField function and they're not getting hit.

Answer (score 1):

Updated mydoghasworm's code with the following changes to fix the "cannot uncheck" issue he was facing with the following two code snippets.

```
            if ( m ) {
                var name = m.name,
                    value = m.value,
                    convert = m.convert;
                if (ev.target.attributes['type'].nodeValue === "checkbox") {
                    value = ev.target.checked;
                }
                if ( convert ) {
                    value = convert( value, ev.target, target );
                }
                if ( value !== undefined ) {
                    $.setField( target, name, value );
                }
```

Also

```
} else if ($(target).is(':checkbox')) {
                //value is whether or not checkbox is clicked
                if (value)
                    $(target).attr('checked', true);
                else
                    $(target).removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: Where does the first snippet go?